# Class not found Exception when creating an object array

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

So, I wrote these class:

```
public class FicherosDeCiudadanos {

   public static int numCiudadanos (File f) {
       try{

           Scanner texto=new Scanner(f);
           int contador=0;
           while(texto.hasNextLine()){
               contador++;
               texto.nextLine();
           }
           texto.close();
           return contador;
       }
   }

   public static  Ciudadano[] leerFichero (File f) {
      try{
          Scanner texto=new Scanner(f);
          //This next line throws classNotFound when debbugging but only 
          //when evaluating Ciudadano[]
          Ciudadano[] tablaCiudadano = new Ciudadano[numCiudadanos(f)];
          ....    
          //TO-DO
   }
}
```

I verified it worked, and it did, the method `leerFichero()` did the job perfectly. It created an object array of `Ciudadano` with the code in TO-DO. But then, in another package, I call the method `leerFichero()` and it gets there, works out `numCiudadanos()` to set the lenght of the array, but then when it gets to `Ciudadano[]` it throws `ClassNotFoundException`, and the program stops. It still works when I use it from its own package.

I'm guessing this is the stack

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
owns: Object  (id=36)   
owns: Object  (id=37)   
ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 286   
ClassNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available 
ClassNotFoundException(ReflectiveOperationException).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available  
ClassNotFoundException.<init>(String) line: not available   
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
FicherosDeCiudadanos.leerFichero(File) line: 54 
Operaciones.nombreCliente(int) line: 80 
Operaciones.listadoCompras() line: 37   
TrabajoProg1.ejecutarOperacion(int) line: 40    
TrabajoProg1.main(String[]) line: 22
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Please verify if the caller (where the code call "leerFichero") has correctly import the class Ciudadano in its classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end that error meant nothing, there was another error later which made it seem like it stopped with this one.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a build path problem. You need to right-click on the outside package and go to

> Build Path > Configure Build Path

and navigate to

> Projects

Then, you click `Add...` and add the project containing `FicherosDeCiudadanos`.

Make sure at the top of your calling class there is the line:

```
import package1.FicherosDeCiudadanos
```

Where `package1` is the package containing `FicherosDeCiudadanos`

Comment: Both packages are in the same project. And the build path includes all packages in the project

Comment: what is line 54 in `leerFichero()`?

Comment: Ciudadano[] tablaCiudadano = new Ciudadano[numCiudadanos(f)];

Comment: the classes Ciudadano and FicherosDeCiudadanos are in the same package and still, both are imported in the class that calls the method    `leerFichero()`. Sorry if I'm difficult to understand

Comment: Make sure that the original file for `Ciudadano` is still accessible from inside Eclipse. It might be that your workspace has "forgotten" where it is, and needs it to be re-imported.

Comment: As in double-click the file and make sure you can still open it from Eclipse

Comment: @galomoribundo was Eclipse able to view your `Ciudadano` class?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the debugger is out of sync with some classes.

Try to Clean/Build project and even relaunch Eclipse (Or other IDE). Then try debugging again.